# Upload excel file to Dropbox or Google Drive?

Tags: android, excel, file, android-intent, android-fileprovider

I'm currently developing an application which creates an excel file(with apache poi) from the sqlite database in android. Everything is working well, except that I can't send the file to another app.
I implemented an fileprovider so I other apps can have permission to my file:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.ria.masterdetailnoten"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

file_paths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="backup" path="backup/"/>
</paths>
```

ExcelFile.java:

```
Uri uriFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ct, "com.example.ria.masterdetailnoten", backupFile);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setDataAndType(uriFile, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose");
ct.startActivity(intent);
```

I know for sure that my file is being created and I can read it again with Apache POI. So the only things which doesn't work is sending the intent to another app.

---

As an example if I choose Google Drive in the intent chooser then following error appears:
"Upload failed: request contained no data."

If I open it with the Mailbox App following error appears:
"Mailbox could not read the selected file"

I hope you can help me guys, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using: `putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriFile)` instead of: `setData(AndType)`?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to work this out with `intent.selector = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply { data = Uri.parse("file:") }`